# How do I make all JavaScript buttons the same size?

Tags: javascript, calculator, calc

How do I make all JavaScript buttons the same size? I am making a calculator and it looks disgusting if all buttons aren't the same size. I have been trying to do this for at least an hour, I couldn't find any StakOverFlow post or tutorial that explained how to do this.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calc</title>
<style>
.calc {border: groove 6px; margin-left: 530px; margin-right: 530px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; height: 200px;}

input {text-align: center;height: 30px;}

.results {padding-bottom: 7px;}

.top {float: left; padding-left: 20px;}

.numbers {float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 15px;}

.symbols {float: right; margin-top: -40px; padding-right: 15px;}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction(clickedId) {
    document.calc.result.value+=clickedId;
}
function Clear() {
    document.calc.result.value="";
}
function compute() {
 try{
 var inp=eval(document.calc.result.value);
 document.calc.result.value=inp;
 }
 catch(err){
  document.calc.result.value="error";
 }
}
function doMath() {
 var inputNum1=document.calc.result.value;
 var result = Math.sqrt(inputNum1);
 document.calc.result.value = result;
}
function myMultiply() {
 var x = parseInt (document.calc.result.value, 10);
 var y = x*x;
 alert(x + " times " + x + " equals " + y);
 return false;
}
function compute() {
 try{
    var inp=eval(document.calc.result.value);
    if(document.calc.result.value==inp)
    inp=inp*inp
    document.calc.result.value=inp;
 }
 catch(err){
  document.calc.result.value="error";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="calc">
<center>
<div class="results">
    <form name="calc">
    <input type="text" name="result" readonly>
    </form>
</div>
<table>
<div class="top">
    <button type="button" id="CLEAR" onclick="Clear()"><font color="#CC0000">C</font></button> <!--Izdzēst rakstīto-->
    <button type="button" id="3.141592653589793" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">π</button> <!--Skaitlis 3.14...-->
    <button type="button" id="6.283185307179586" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">τ</button> <!--Skaitlis 6.28...-->
</div>
<br>
<div class="numbers">
    <button type="button" id="1" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">1</button> <!--Skaitlis 1-->
    <button type="button" id="2" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">2</button> <!--Skaitlis 2-->
    <button type="button" id="3" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">3</button> <!--Skaitlis 3-->
<br>
    <button type="button" id="4" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">4</button> <!--Skaitlis 4-->
    <button type="button" id="5" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">5</button> <!--Skaitlis 5-->
    <button type="button" id="6" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">6</button> <!--Skaitlis 6-->
<br>
    <button type="button" id="7" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">7</button> <!--Skaitlis 7-->
    <button type="button" id="8" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">8</button> <!--Skaitlis 8-->
    <button type="button" id="9" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">9</button> <!--Skaitlis 9-->
<br>
    <button type="button" id="0" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">0</button> <!--Skaitlis 0-->
</div>
<br>
<div class="symbols">
    <button type="button" id="ANS" onclick="compute()">=</button> <!--Vienādības zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="*" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">x</button> <!--Reizināšanas zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="/" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">÷</button> <!--Dalīšanas zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="+" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">+</button> <!--Plusa zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="-" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">-</button> <!--Mīnusa zīme-->
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="SQRT" onclick="doMath()">√</button> <!--Kvadrātsakne-->
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="imp*inp" onclick="compute()"><sub>2</sub></button> <!--Kvadrāts-->
</div>
<br>
</table>
</center>
</div>
<center>
<p>Special thanks to my peeps at <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverFlow</a> for helping me with some issues!</p> <!--Pateicības piezīme-->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give them a class name, use `getElementsByClassName()` and a for loop to set the new css to all elements with that class name?

Comment: There wouldn't be a stack overflow tutorial on this. Firstly you would need to format your buttons neatly in html using a table or bootstrap. Then you just set the height / width in the css

Answer (score 3):

Try adding some CSS :

```
button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via CSS, no JS necessary:

```
.symbols button{
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

This targets all of the buttons within the symbols div.

You can also make it more generic:

```
button{
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

Which will then style every button on the page.